# Rails: destroying a finder_sql association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got a model relation in Rails 3.0.3 that uses `:finder_sql`, like this (SQL omitted for readability):

```
has_many :permissions, :finder_sql => 'SELECT * FROM ...', :readonly => false
```

Listing those permissions works just find, but when I try to destroy one, I can't.

In the Rails console, I can call `.destroy` and it returns the object. If I then call `.destroyed?`, it returns true. But it doesn't actually delete the table row.

**How can I destroy this associated object?** I added the `:readonly => false` above as an attempt to solve this problem, but no luck yet.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The SQL itself was the problem. I did this:

```
'Select * FROM `permissions` INNER JOIN ...'
```

Because I selected * FROM multiple tables, each of which has an `id` column, MySQL returned the last table's `id` attribute.

The solution was to do this:

```
'SELECT `permissions`.* FROM `permissions` INNER JOIN ...'
```

Now I'm only getting attributes from the permissions table itself, so I have the correct ID and the delete succeeds.

Comment: Incidentally, this sort of thing is why, at my last PHP job, we had primary key columns like `permissons`.`permissions_id` - it prevents ambiguity and clashes. It also lets you shorten joins from things like `ON foo.id = bar.foo_id` to `USING foo_id`, since both the primary and foreign key are named `foo_id`.